# How to use the max-time tag with klee

Tags: echo, llvm, gnu-coreutils, klee

I'm trying to run klee on a compiled bytecode version of the coreutils, somewhat replicating the experiment that klee did a while back.

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to use the --max-time flag.

When I run this command, it takes around 3 minutes, despite the max-time being 10 seconds:

```
klee --optimize --libc=uclibc --posix-runtime --max-time 10s ./echo.bc --sym-args 0 1 10 --sym-args 0 2 2 --sym-files 1 8 --sym-stdin 8 --sym-stdout
```

When I run this command, it takes around 3 seconds. The command is identical, except for the fact that the filename and the --max-time flag are switched.

```
klee --optimize --libc=uclibc --posix-runtime --max-time 10s ./echo.bc --sym-args 0 1 10 --sym-args 0 2 2 --sym-files 1 8 --sym-stdin 8 --sym-stdout
```

Finally, when I run it without the --max-time flag

```
klee --optimize --libc=uclibc --posix-runtime ./echo.bc --sym-args 0 1 10 --sym-args 0 2 2 --sym-files 1 8 --sym-stdin 8 --sym-stdout
```

it takes at least 30 minutes, at which point I gave up and killed it.

Clearly, the flag before and after the filename are both doing something, but I'm not sure what. The standard usage for --max-time puts it before the filename according to the documentation. Can anyone help me understand what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

KLEE uses llvm's implementation of command line argument preprocessor [there](https://github.com/klee/klee/blob/master/tools/klee/main.cpp#L70) . And since `InputFile` option is a positional argument, all following ones are ignored.
However, such options as `--sym-args`, `--sym-files`, `--sym-stdin` are processed in [POSIX runtime](https://github.com/klee/klee/blob/master/runtime/POSIX/klee_init_env.c) independently.